# Converting many string values to categories

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with one column full of string values. They need to be converted into categories. Due to huge amount it would be inconvenient to define categories in dictionary. Is there any other way in pandas to do that?

Comment: You could learn about groupby.may that help

Answer (score 0):

I applied below command and it works:
df['kategorie']=action['kategorie'].astype('category')